# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'email')

Tags: javascript, authentication, postman, typeerror

I'm trying to authenticate user. Sign-up is working fine but in sign-in req.body.email is undefined and I can't figure out why.
Here is my code for sign-in:

```
router.post('/signin',(res,req,next)=>{
    User.findOne({ email: req.body.email })
    .exec()
    .then(user => {
        if(user.length<1){
            return res.status(401).json({
                message: 'Auth Failed'
            })
        }
        bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, this.user[0].password, (err,result)=>{
            if(err){
                return res.status(401).json({
                    message: 'Auth Failed'
                });
            }
            if(result){
                return res.status(200).json({
                    message: 'Auth Successful'
                });
            }
            res.status(401).json({
                message: 'Auth Failed'
            });
        })
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json({
            error: err
        });
    })
    
})
```

On Postman:

```
{
    "email": "test@gmail.com",
    "password": "12345"
}
```

Console Error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'email')
    at C:\Users\SJPC\auth\routes\user.route.js:62:37
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\SJPC\auth\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\SJPC\auth\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\SJPC\auth\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\SJPC\auth\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\SJPC\auth\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\SJPC\auth\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:341:12)
    at next (C:\Users\SJPC\auth\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (C:\Users\SJPC\auth\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
    at router (C:\Users\SJPC\auth\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)
```

I have tried req.query.email but it also thrown the same error.

Comment: The first thing to do would be to `console.log(req.body)` to see if the items are passed in the body as you expect

Comment: You need to add Content-type header to your request at postman
Add "Content-Type: application/json" because your request body is json data

Answer (score 0):

You should add this code

```js
app.use(express.json())
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Also, the correct order of parameters is (req, res, next). next is only needed if you are performing a callback.
I don't know if this will completely fix your problem but it won't hurt.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

So I was using edge and had the same problem, but as soon as I switched over to chrome the problem was gone. I hope I can prevent someone from losing some hours on this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, something similar happens to me but with nextjs Next-auth when I work with a provider like google. you just have to add the ? in each variable of the object. It's very strange but it worked for me. following the logic of your code it would be

```
User.findOne({ email: req?.body?.email ?? 'no-email'})
```

the same with password

```
bcrypt.compare(req?.body?.password ?? 'no-pass', this.user[0].password, (err,result)=>{....
```

In my case it was this from nextauth

my error

```
[next-auth][error][JWT_SESSION_ERROR]
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#jwt_session_error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'email') {
  message: "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'email')",
```

solution

```
async jwt({ token, user }) {
    // console.log(user.email);
    const email = user?.email ?? 'no-email'; // here
    const dbUser = await prisma.user.findUnique({ where: { email } }); // will always have email because I go through signIn
    // console.log(dbUser);
    if (dbUser?.isActive === false) throw new Error('User disabled'); // we can avoid logging in in case the user is deactivated/blocked // ! we can also send null
    if (dbUser !== null) { // this verification is necessary
    token.role = dbUser?.role; // here also
    token.id = dbUser?.id; // here
    }return token };
```